# How to add a function to execute when a YouTube video is done playing?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

So let's say that I embed a youtube video, and when it's done playing, I want it to do this function. How would I detect that the video is done playing?

I'm assuming that the video varies in length. So I know the video will be done in 5 minutes but I want to generalize it so that when an "x" minute video is done playing it calls this function.

This all the HTML that I have if it matters.... (excuse the cat video lol)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Discovery</title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDuLeXx2Gv0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YouTube offers an api for this, look it up.

Comment: You can may try this stackoverflow link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896625/how-to-call-a-function-on-video-end-html5-and-mediaelementjs

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Youtube you can do something like this:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {          
        alert('done');
    }
}
```

Side note: You'll need to include the Youtube API before this script in order for it to work.

`<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>`

Working code pen - http://codepen.io/rr1000/pen/vEyNLj

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status). Check if `player.getPlayerState()==0`, which indicates that it ended.