# Video ended function not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, video

I'm trying to make an image appear when the video reaches the end but it's not working and for now I have this code:

```
// Change image to video on click(working)
$('#image').click(function() {
  video = '<video id="video" muted autoplay poster="/img.png" controls style="width: 100%; height: auto; z-index: 999999;"><source src="/video.m4v"></video>';
  jQuery(this).replaceWith(video);
});

// Detect end of video(not working)
$('video').on('ended', function() {
   alert("End of te video!");
});
```

The alert is not popping out, keep in mind that this code works fine on desktop, but not on mobile, any suggestion would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: As you're replacing the `video` element completely you may need to use a delegated event handler: `$(document).on('ended', 'video', function() ... `

Comment: jQuery Version: jquery.js?ver=1.12.4, Rory McCrossan code didn't work: jQuery(document).on('ended', 'video', function(){
alert("132");
});

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new EventListener for the ended events

Example:

```
video.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    //Your Code goes here
})

success: function (video, domObject) { 

    // add event listener
    YourMediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {

           //Do Stuff here

    }, false);
```

i copied the code from the below link checck that for more info...

[How to call a function on video end ? (HTML5 and mediaelementjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896625/how-to-call-a-function-on-video-end-html5-and-mediaelementjs)

Comment: What do you think `$('video').on('ended')` is doing?